# show hidden div when element is moused over and keep displayed until mouse leaves either element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This should be really simple, but I am new at this and I think I am overthinking things. I want to reveal an element when another element is hovered over, and keep it displayed if the user is moused over either one.

Here is what I'm starting with, and I have tried to write an if statement to say if element is showing and hovered over, keep it displayed, but it didn't change the behavior you see [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmGpf/6/).

In the example, I want the "i am a link" text to stay there if the user moves their mouse to try to click on it.  I have found other posts on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503247/keep-hover-state-applied-until-user-mouses-over-another-element) but haven't been able to apply their answers to solve my question.

[If you look at this page](http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/editorial/manolo042913.jsp), and hover over a shoe, you can see the exact effect I'm trying to achieve. The product info is revealed and you can move your mouse to click on it.

```
$("#caribbean-info").mouseenter(function () {
    $('#example3-link1').slideDown(400);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('#example3-link1').slideUp(400);
});
```

I also tried to do something like this, which doesn't work:

```
$("#caribbean-info").mouseenter(function () {
    $('#example3-link1').slideDown(400).hover(function () {
        $('#example3-link1').show();
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $('#example3-link1').hide();
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('#example3-link1').slideUp(400);
});
```

Please show me the light!

Comment: Your fiddle does not load jQuery. If it does your code works, although the css is a little bit off, but if you look to the lower right side of the div while hovering, you'll see the link appear.

Comment: The code on your fiddle is working as you want it to, just remember to include the jquery library for your fiddle.

Comment: With jQuery library works ok ;)

Comment: Why are you all saying it works??  In the question the OP states `I want to reveal an element when another element is hovered over, and keep it displayed if the user is moused over either one.`  It disappears as soon as you leave the 1st element.

Comment: it is loading jquery 1.3.2 as an external resource, no? the site i am making this for uses 1.3.2 without chance of upgrading.  When I move the mouse from the white box, over the "I Am A Link", the I Am A link slides back up. I want it to stay...

Comment: So the link should show when the user hovers over the div, but what action should hide the link? The mouse leaving the link?

Comment: @surfbird0713 - no it's not included.

Comment: The mouse leaving either #example3-link1 or #caribbean-info should hide the link.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle link so hopefully you can see jquery loaded. Also added a link to another site that has what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Your saks example doesn't really go with your fiddle because the link in the saks example is on top of the show image, where in your example the link is next to the div. In your example you have to leave the div to reach the link but in the saks example you're still hovering over the shoe.

Comment: Oh really? When I inspected the shoe element it looked like an image map and the links revealed from it went beyond that area. I'll look again.

Comment: @surfbird0713 I've added a working answer below.  Let me know if that's not what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap both the div and the link in a container then you can simply apply the mouseenter and mouseleave events to that...

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dmGpf/8/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="caribbean-info"></div>
    <a href="#test" id="example3-link1">I am a link - click here.</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#container").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#example3-link1").slideDown();
});
$("#container").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#example3-link1").slideUp();
});
```

**CSS**

I also made a slight change to the css so that the link would only show when you hovered above the visible part of `#caribbean-info`.  I just set display to inline-block:

```
#caribbean-info{
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely close, the only thing is that if you mouse above the link it's still showing. Maybe I have to make an image map that includes both the product and space where link will appear, and use that as the "container" and apply your approach?

Comment: Try the jsfiddle link now.  I've just made `#caribbean-info` `display:inline-block` so it doesn't automatically fill the page horizontally.  You can now hover at the side of it and the link doesn't show :)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted.  Not the kind of answer I was expecting, just to wrap in a container. Good work, thanks so much! Will you update your answer to add the CSS adjustment as well?

Comment: check out this fiddle. It is not consistent - sometimes #example-link1 slides up and down when it should be staying still. Any ideas?  http://jsfiddle.net/pFucC/

Comment: The link shows when you hover over the div, exactly as it previously did.  Are you saying now that it should show when you hover over the image instead?

Comment: No, what you had previously is exactly what I'm looking for, but when I hover over the area in my image, it doesn't work consistently. Sometimes it is exactly like you set it up, but other times the text slides up and down the whole time the mouse is over it.  Not sure whats going on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37601/discussion-between-surfbird0713-and-archer)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need  a script for that (as long as the target element [e.g. the one that need to appear] can be 'selected' with CSS selectors from the hovered element)

that means that the target element can be nested in the hovered one, or that the hovered element is a preceding sibling of the target)
otherwise, you'll have to use a script.

see this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/WdyeW/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="Hovered">Hover me</div>
<div id="Target">I'm the target</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Target
{
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}
#Hovered
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#Target:hover, #Hovered:hover + #Target
{
    display: block;
}
```

**Update**

even if you want some coll transition, it still can be done via pure CSS
See this [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/WdyeW/2/)

Comment: How does that make the link slide up and slide down?

Comment: @Archer the sliding thing is not a specification. its is way of doing it. in the question the OP just wanted appearing/dissapearing

Comment: Sigh.  This is totally wrong, and you really shouldn't go deciding what is and isn't important to the OP.

Comment: @Archer I'm not deciding anything. He didn't ask for that.

Comment: Okay.  Good luck     :)

Comment: @Archer if the sliding is the only reason you voted down, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote you actually - I was trying to help you get a better answer.  I've already supplied her with a working answer anyway, but thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/ZYeHF/) , link wrapped inside div, works like you wanted ;)

```
<div id="caribbean-info">
  <a href="#test" id="example3-link1">I am a link - click here.</a>
</div>


$("#caribbean-info").mouseenter(function() {
  $('#example3-link1').stop().slideDown(400);  
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('#example3-link1').stop().delay(800).slideUp(400);
});
$('#example3-link1').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't disappear when you leave `#caribbean-info`

Comment: You can't have both. If link disappear when you live `#caribbean-info` how you suppose to click on it? I'll try something on Fiddle now...

Comment: They have both on this site - hover over the shoe: http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/editorial/manolo042913.jsp

Comment: I hovered over shoe and it's not perfect. I've updated Fiddle, added delay.